# Matlab mynorm function

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert a code from Matlab to Python in which I came across a function named `mynorm(x,y)` in Matlab which I want to convert to Python. I searched equivalent for this function in Python but was not successful. So tried to find the implementation of this function on the net and found a small mynorm.m file which contains the function with just one-liner code which is as follows:

```
function L = mynorm(x,y)
%length of the vector [x,y]
L = sqrt(x^2 + y^2);
%note - if the input was a vector v, a better way to do this would be
%L = sqrt(dot(v,v)) 
%see help dot for the dot product. This would work for vectors of any size.
```

But when I looked into the call which is made to this function in matlab file, it is as follows:

```
feaNorm = mynorm(fea2, 1)
feaNorm = mynorm(iris(:,1:4),2);
```

which doesn't really look like length function as in the above implementation.

Thus, I am skeptical to use sqrt function in Python for this function call.

Can someone redirect me to the correct implementation or the equivalent python code?

Comment: A function from the internet with the same name will almost certainly not do the same as the function used by your code. Especially if it something as "individual" and nondescriptive as `mynorm`.

Comment: Yes. I too thought earlier that this must be their own function but couldn't find any function definition in the whole project directory. The same function is used in several places in exactly the same way. Check out .. https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54764-feature-selection-by-eigenvector-centrality?focused=7171054&tab=function

Comment: Are you *sure* you need the function at all? :) In the function you linked the part that calls `mynorm` seems to be unreachable. I have not used Matlab in quite a while but I don't think execution continues past the `return` statement...

Comment: The link was only for reference. I am not using the code from the link. I am trying to run a code from a github repository and in that project, it is getting executed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `hypot` trigonometric function available in the `math` module. You will find a description of the `math` module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html).

Comment: great.. thanks a lot.. will include this in python file.